# Installing Cloud SDK error (MacOS) — ImportError: No module named zlib

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I am setting up Cloud SDK on my Macbook using Terminal.

I am just following these steps: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos

While trying the "./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh" command I get this error:

```
Ashwins-Mac:~ ashwinchalaka$ cd Downloads/
Ashwins-Mac:Downloads ashwinchalaka$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 44, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 33, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import http
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/http.py", line 29, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import http_proxy
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/http_proxy.py", line 26, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from httplib2.python2.httplib2 import *
  File "/Users/ashwinchalaka/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

All I am trying to do is setup the SDK so I can deploy my Python-Django app to GCP.

I've already tried a number of suggestions from other forums. Reinstalling python (with brew), trying to sudo install zlib files. It feels like I just made a mess, I am not sure how to clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the command line (install xcode):

```
xcode-select --install
```

It should include zlib in. Then try to rerun `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`.
Hope it help.